# IOS 14 Asking Permission to Track

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, appstore-approval, ios14

We have integrated Facebook iOS SDK and Firebase to our iOS APP.
Facebook SDK is being used for analytics and Firebase is being used to monitor for crashes and performance issues.

At no point, these SDKs are used to display any advertisements for the users and we do not share any personal details of users such as email address, age, address, etc. with these SDKs.

We are confused about whether we should ask for user permission for tracking or not under the new privacy requirements of iOS 14. Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: From what I understand the Facebook SDK won‘t track any events unless you asked the user for permission. It also looks like you have to call setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled and set it to true after the user gave permission.

Comment: @Maci ok got it thanks!